# How to enable/disable SWT Text WRAP in runtime

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I have a SWT button (with SWT.CHECK flag) and SWT Text. 
Upon pressed, SWT button should enable/disable the wrapping of the SWT text.

I am aware that text wrapping capability is specified in the constructor as follow:

```
new Text(parent, SWT.WRAP)
```

But I couldn't find a method such as setWrap(false) to programmatically enable/disable it in runtime.

Is there a way to do this in SWT? 
Or the only solution is to dispose the old text, and create a new one with different flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general SWT styles can't be changed and this is the case for the Wrap style of the `Text` control.

The `StyledText` control does have a `setWordWrap(boolean)` method, you should be able to use that.